# How can i get AG dashboard values via SQL Query across all supported versions of SQL server

Tags: sql-server, performance, availability-groups, high-availability, dmv

I am trying to ease the monitoring of availability groups across multiple SQL servers.

Came across few dmvs which got me the data. But cannot figure out some important columns which i am seeing in SSMS AG Dashboard report. How can i get this data via SQL query. We cannot use PS unfortunately as its blocked to get data remotely

Columns in SSMS dashboard which i cannot find in dmv are below. Do we know from where these metrics are getting populated?

> Estimate Data Loss (seconds)
>
> Estimated Recovery Time (seconds)
>
> Synchronization Performance (seconds)
>
> Issues:
>
> Connection state
>
> Last connection error no:

Answer (score 0):

Some of the columns in the Availability Group Dashboard are calculated, such as the **Estimated Recovery Time (seconds)** which you can replicate by dividing the `redo_queue_size` by the `redo_rate` in the [`sys.dm_hadr_database_replica_states` DMV](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-hadr-database-replica-states-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15).

Comment: Appreciate your answer. How about other columns? Is there any link which confirms where to look for the details on these or columns in SSSMS dashboard?